# Unsigned literals in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

How do I use unsigned literals in assignments?

Take a look at this example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 

entity myTest is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC );
end myTest;

architecture Behavioral of myTest is

  signal testSignal : unsigned (31 downto 0);

begin
    process (clk) is
    begin
        if (rising_edge (clk)) then

           -- this compiles fine:
            testSignal <= testSignal + 1;

            -- this causes an error. Why?
            testSignal <= 1;

        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The line:

```
            testSignal <= 1;
```

results in the following error message on Xilinx ISE:

`Line 22. Type of testSignal is incompatible with type of 1.`

Can anyone explain why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is overloaded in `ieee.numeric_std` for `unsigned` and `integer`, which is why the first line works; however, assignment is not (and cannot be), and since `1` is an integer literal, it cannot be assigned directly to an `unsigned` (which is a vector); it must be converted first. The standard method is:

```
testSignal <= to_unsigned(1, testSignal'length);
```

`to_unsigned()` takes 2 arguments: a `natural` to convert, and the vector length to convert to.

Comment: In addition to fru1tbat's answer, you can also use direct vector assignments with binary or hex values like this `testSignal <= x"00023AD5";` or set every bit to zero like this `testSignal <= (others => '0');` P.S. you should add an initialization value to your counter's signal declaration :)